# Record search in MS Access with recordset.findfirst throws error 3070

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to build an MS Access database.

One of the elements is an autofill in a record management form.

Form layout:

[image: The layout of the form is like this]

Note that the Battery ID & Model Number is in one table (referred as Table 1), and the Chemistry Type, Spec Voltage, Spec Capacity is stored in another table based on Model Number (referred as Table 2). The two tables are joined in the relationship with a one-to-many relation at the Model Number entry.

What I would like to achieve is to give the user the ability to enter a Battery ID, using `afterupdate()`, search Table 1, get the Model Number, if the Battery ID entry already exists. Then search Table 2, get the battery model details, if it exists.

[image: To clarify the flow, here is the flowchart]

The "Search Table 1 for matching Battery ID" part worked with the following code:

```vb
Private Sub txtBatteryID_AfterUpdate()
    'Set the path to the Battery Records table
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Batteries for Portable Radios", dbOpenDynaset)

    'do a findfirst search for the Battery ID, using value from textbox txtBatteryID
    RS.FindFirst "[Battery ID]=" & txtBatteryID

    'If no matching record, leave the other fields empty
    If RS.NoMatch Then
        cmbModelNumber.Value = Null
        cmbChemistryType.Value = Null
        txtSpecVoltage.Value = Null
        txtSpecCapacity.Value = Null
    'If there is a matching record, then, grab the model number
    Else
        cmbModelNumber.Value = RS("Model Number")
        'as there is an existing record with model number, run a search on the model number and grab the model info
        Call cmbModelNumber_AfterUpdate
    End If
    'close recordset
    RS.Close
    'clear recordset path
    Set RS = Nothing
End Sub
```

For the "Search Table 2 for matching Model Number" part, I thought it would be the same structure:

```vb
Private Sub cmbModelNumber_AfterUpdate()
    'Set the path to the Model Records table
    Set ModelRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblInfoBatteryModelByModel#", dbOpenDynaset)

    'do a findfirst search for the Model Number, using value from combobox cmbModelNumber
    ModelRS.FindFirst "[Model Number]=" & cmbModelNumber

    'If no matching record, leave the other fields empty
    If ModelRS.NoMatch Then
        cmbChemistryType.Value = Null
        txtSpecVoltage.Value = Null
        txtSpecCapacity.Value = Null
     'If there is a matching record, then, grab the Model Info
    Else
        cmbChemistryType.Value = ModelRS("Chemistry Type")
        txtSpecVoltage.Value = ModelRS("Spec Voltage (V)")
        txtSpecCapacity.Value = ModelRS("Spec Capacity (mAh)")
    End If
    'close recordset
    ModelRS.Close
    'clear recordset path
    Set ModelRS = Nothing

End Sub
```

except this time when I type in an existing Battery ID or Model Number, it throws a 3070 error.

Error message:

[image: Error Message]

Problematic line:

[image: Problematic Line]

I have no clue why this wouldn't take the value.

Comment: Your showing twice the error line, not the error mesage. What is the erropr mesage?

Comment: Please provide variable type and value of cmbModelNumber when the error occurs.

Comment: fixed, my bad. the error is "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize 'NNTN8560A' as a valid field name or expression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `Model Number` field looks to be a string, you will need to surround the criteria value supplied to the `FindFirst` method with either single or double quotes, e.g.:

```vb
ModelRS.FindFirst "[Model Number]='" & cmbModelNumber & "'"
```

Or:

```vb
ModelRS.FindFirst "[Model Number]=""" & cmbModelNumber & """"
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! This multi-layers of quotation marks got me confused. XD